# Java: Sleep or Wait until a specific time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following static method that once the `reqStreamingData` method of `obj` is called, it starts retrieving data from client server constantly at a rate of 150 ms.

```
public static void streamingDataOperations(ClientSocket cs) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    // call - retrieve streaming data constantly from client server
    cs.reqStreamingData(); // <- this method comes from client's API.

   // Want to cancel the data request when the current time is after 05:30:00 am. 
   cancelData(cs);

}
```

At the moment, I have written the code below to cancel the data request but it is constantly evaluating the time condition and I do not know if this is inefficient or not, given that the thread is currently already receiving a lot of data from client side at such a high frequency. I know that I can also simply do `Thread.sleep(sometime)` but is there a way I can specify the thread to `sleep` or `wait` until a specific time condition is met and then cancel the data?

```
public static void cancelData(ClientSocket cs) throws InterruptedException{
       while(LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime().compareTo(LocalTime.of(05,30)) <= 0) 
       {
       }
       cs.cancelStreamingData();  // <- this method comes from client's API. 

}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at `java.util.Timer`? You really should *not* do a waiting loop. Certainly not the one you have written (which is a resource hog), and a `sleep` based one is not recommended either.

Comment: So you just want to cancel `cs.cancelStreamingData()` at a time point in future?
You can create a `TimerTask`, and run it with `Timer` at a specific time point.

Comment: Thanks. I just wrote a new class that extends `TimerTask` and included the static `cancelStreamingData` method inside the `run` method. It seems to work for now. Would update the question if I run into new difficulties. Thank you very much.